# How to calculate duration, in minutes, by condition?

Tags: r

**MY DATASET**

My dataset includes the start and finish times of many people (`ID`) working in different areas (`Location`) on various days of the week (`Day`). An example of my dataset is below:

```
> head(WeekOne, 15)
                 Start              Finish Day     ID Location
1  2017-04-12 00:00:00 2017-04-12 00:02:55  D1 Daniel   Office
2  2017-04-12 00:02:55 2017-04-12 00:06:18  D1 Daniel   Office
3  2017-04-12 00:06:18 2017-04-12 00:08:20  D1 Daniel   OnSite
4  2017-04-12 00:08:20 2017-04-12 00:08:40  D1 Daniel   OnSite
5  2017-04-12 00:08:40 2017-04-12 00:10:11  D1 Daniel   Travel
6  2017-04-12 00:10:11 2017-04-12 00:10:18  D1 Daniel   Travel
7  2017-04-12 00:10:18 2017-04-12 00:17:52  D1 Daniel   Travel
8  2017-04-12 00:17:52 2017-04-12 00:19:00  D1 Daniel   Travel
9  2017-04-12 00:19:00 2017-04-12 00:19:56  D1 Daniel   OnSite
10 2017-04-12 00:19:56 2017-04-12 00:28:48  D1 Daniel   OnSite
11 2017-04-12 00:00:00 2017-04-12 00:03:52  D2 Daniel   OnSite
12 2017-04-12 00:03:52 2017-04-12 00:04:05  D2 Daniel   Office
13 2017-04-12 00:04:05 2017-04-12 00:08:32  D2 Daniel   Office
14 2017-04-12 00:08:32 2017-04-12 00:16:01  D2 Daniel   Travel
15 2017-04-12 00:16:01 2017-04-12 00:25:35  D2 Daniel   OnSite
```

I wish to know the total time, in minutes, each `ID` spends at each `Location` over the week. The maximum level of `Day` is D7 and I have a seperate data.frame for each week. Therefore, I only need to iterate across `Location` and `ID`.

**WHAT I HAVE ATTEMPTED**

The code below, although this returns minutes in a strange format and does not account for multiple visits to the same location on one day. For example, Daniel visits `OnSite` twice on `D1`.

```
WeekOne %>% 
  group_by(ID, Location) %>% 
  summarise(Duration = max(Finish) - min(Start))
```

I did think of creating a new column `WeekOne$Level` that accounts for multiple and changes in `Location`. I could then iterate over each Level and use the code above. For example:

```
> head(WeekOne, 15)
                 Start              Finish Day     ID Location Level
1  2017-04-12 00:00:00 2017-04-12 00:02:55  D1 Daniel   Office 1
2  2017-04-12 00:02:55 2017-04-12 00:06:18  D1 Daniel   Office 1
3  2017-04-12 00:06:18 2017-04-12 00:08:20  D1 Daniel   OnSite 2
4  2017-04-12 00:08:20 2017-04-12 00:08:40  D1 Daniel   OnSite 2
5  2017-04-12 00:08:40 2017-04-12 00:10:11  D1 Daniel   Travel 3
6  2017-04-12 00:10:11 2017-04-12 00:10:18  D1 Daniel   Travel 3
7  2017-04-12 00:10:18 2017-04-12 00:17:52  D1 Daniel   Travel 3
8  2017-04-12 00:17:52 2017-04-12 00:19:00  D1 Daniel   Travel 3
9  2017-04-12 00:19:00 2017-04-12 00:19:56  D1 Daniel   OnSite 4
10 2017-04-12 00:19:56 2017-04-12 00:28:48  D1 Daniel   OnSite 4
11 2017-04-12 00:00:00 2017-04-12 00:03:52  D2 Daniel   OnSite 5 
12 2017-04-12 00:03:52 2017-04-12 00:04:05  D2 Daniel   Office 6
13 2017-04-12 00:04:05 2017-04-12 00:08:32  D2 Daniel   Office 6
14 2017-04-12 00:08:32 2017-04-12 00:16:01  D2 Daniel   Travel 7
15 2017-04-12 00:16:01 2017-04-12 00:25:35  D2 Daniel   OnSite 8

WeekOne %>% 
  group_by(ID, Level) %>% 
  summarise(Duration = max(Finish) - min(Start))
```

However, I am unsure how to even add this column in, it doesn't account for `Location`, seems cumbersome and doesn't address the issue with minutes returning in a funny format.

**MY QUESTION**

How can I quickly and easily calculate the total duration of `Location` by each `ID` over time? I would like duration to be in minutes, rounded to the nearest minute. For example: 3 mins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to calculate the duration first and then get the sum by ID and location:

```
WeekOne %>% 
      mutate(Duration = Finish - Start) %>%
      group_by(ID, Location) %>% 
      summarize(Total_Duration = round(sum(Duration) / 60, 1))
```

Comment: What is the format of this `Total_Duration`? For example, I am given a number 933.50000238419 but how do I get `Total_Duration` in minutes?

Comment: It looks like you're at seconds atm, so just divide by 60 to get minutes